# doesn’t get up early vs wasn't getting up early

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Am I right Sam does it every day? If it's only today, it will be the second version.

> Sam doesn’t get up early enough to catch the 7.30 train. If he got up earlier, he wouldn’t be late.
>
> Sam wasn't getting up early enough to catch the 7.30 train. If he got up earlier, he wouldn’t be late.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was 'only today', it would be *Sam didn't get up early enough [today] to catch the 7.30 train. If he had got up earlier he wouldn't have been late.*

*Sam wasn't getting up early enough* implies that this was his habit at some time in the past; he might be more punctual now. However, the second sentence would have to be *If he had got up earlier he wouldn't have been late.*